# Proper Hibernate Many-to-Many collections mapping?

Tags: hibernate, mapping, many-to-many

I'm new to the Hibernate, so there is the problem.
I have bidirectional many-to-many association and each one of them have collection of another entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "likes", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "uid", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "jid", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private Set<Joke> likedJokes  = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "favorites", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "uid", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "jid", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private Set<Joke> favoriteJokes  = new HashSet<>();
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "JOKES")
public class Joke {
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "likedJokes", cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<User> likedByUsers = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "favoriteJokes", cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
private Set<User> inFavorites = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

This cause the situation, when i can't delete Joke, which contains in any User m-t-m collection(and these Users contains in Joke collection). Or, if i adding REMOVE to the cascade hibernate deletes Users and all their Jokes. I don't see any solutions for this problem, except delete all links manually

```
//foreach "double-linked" collections
for (User u : joke.getCollectionWithUsers()) { 
    User user = userService.getUserWithActivatedCollections(u.getId());
    user.getAppropriateCollectionWithJokes().remove(joke);
}
```

but i think this is not good.

So, is this a logical error and i shouldn't do it like that, or there is a way to do it right using current mapping?

If it can helps, i use 4.3.10.Final version of hibernate.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't understand your problem. Could you articulate it in another way, maybe with an example? Moreover, `@ManyToMany` for `likedJokes` is missing.

Comment: Indeed, annotation was missed, tnx, fixed. ok, there is a simle example. I have five jokes. One of them have two likes. When i deleting it joke, hibernate also deletes users, who likes it, and also rest of their jokes. I want to delete a joke with its links in join tanle, not with all entities in it's collections.

Comment: You must indeed remove the joke from the likedJokes and favoriteJokes before removing the Joke. That's expected.

Comment: AFAIK, yes, this is the only solution.

Comment: @JBNizet I added some code for cleaning collections in post, is it the only(or at least not bad) proper solution?